# Why am I getting this error message on ipp320

Tags: smartcard, payment-processing, emv

I am working on developing an EMV solution for ipp320.  I had to reboot the device and now I am getting the following error message from the device when I start to run a transaction and I confirm the amount.

"Index Key is Missing.  Please remove card".

Does anyone have any input on this?

Answer (score 1):

Answer yourself:

- Which EMV card you using? Which Application ID (**AID** tag 0x84)?
- Your **Terminal Capability** (tag *0x9f33*) was set for **SDA/DDA/CDA**?
- Check your card-terminal conversation to get **Certification Authority Public Key Index** (tag *0x8F*)?
- Do you load the correspondent CA Public Keys into terminal?

I am sure the card and terminal deal about checking SDA/DDA/CDA Offline Authentification. For offline flows required to have CA Public Keys loaded into terminal. Usually it is table where CA Public Key Modules (Values) linked to AID and Public Key Index.

From your terminal message the CA PK value missed. Offline Authentication failed. Due to Terminal Action Codes (TACs) the transaction was declined immediately without try to get online approval.